# Number Theory Puzzle: Competition Problem

Tags: number-theory

I have been struggling the past few hours with a problem I initially thought to be easy and simple. Nothing comes to mind besides guessing numbers and the answer. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You!

Problem:

**If any digit of a given 4-digit number is deleted, the resulting 3-digit number is a divisor of the original number. How many 4-digit numbers have this property?**

Answer (score 2):

Let the number be $abcd$. The letters represent digits and writing one after another is a multidigit number, not multiplication.

Striking $d$ we have $abc|abcd$, which tells us that $d=0$.

Then striking $c$ we have $ab0|abc0$, which gives $c=0$.

Finally we have $a00|ab00$ and $b00|ab00$.  This shows both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero as zero does not divide anything.

We have $a|b$ and $b|a0$.  This is true if $a=b$, if $b=2a$, or if $b=5a$  This gives fourteen numbers:  $$1100,1200,1500,2200,2400,3300,3600,4400,4800,5500,6600,7700,8800,9900$$

Comment: You missed $4800$...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the notation, but understand the concept. Why is it safe to assume that d and c = 0 ?

Comment: We have $abcd=10\cdot abc+d$, so unless $d=0, abc$ will not divide $abcd$.  The same argument works for $c$ once we know $d=0$

Answer (score 2):

We have $14$ such numbers. With the numbers @RossMillikan sir have noted, we also can have $a|ab$ and $b|ab$ case. Which will give numbers like $1200,1500,2400,3600,4800$. The full list is given below: $$ 1100, 1200, 1500, 2200, 2400, 3300, 3600, 4400, 4800, 5500, 6600, 7700, 8800, 9900$$

Comment: I don't think $a000$ qualifies because if we strike the $a$ we are left with $000|a000$, which is not true.

Comment: Yeah, $a000$ is not such number. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can't have $000$ as a divisor.  Back down to $14$.